# Automatic sorting

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sorting

Is it possible to get nhibernate to sort lists on a specific property/column (if no sorting have been specified)? Maybe in the mapping files or in some other way?

Comment: I don't understand...are you talking about child collections; or specifying a default sort order when getting a list of aggregate roots?

Comment: `Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ICustomer)).List()` would generate `SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY name`

Comment: AFAIK you can only do this for collections, but not for root entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as of today.

would like something like:

```
<nhibernate-mapping>
    <class default-order-by="Name">
        <property name="Name" column="name" />
    </class>
</nhibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code below :

Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ICustomer))
.AddOrder(Order.Desc("name") )
.List();

Comment: You missed this part: `if no sorting have been specified`. I want to be able to specify default sorting if none have been specified.